# Regex pattern for string

Tags: c#, regex, string, unity-game-engine

i am trying to get specific information from text file. My string looks like this:

```
1.001
{
position = (0,0,0);
rotation = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}

1.002
{
rotation = (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}

2.001
{
spawnOnStart = False;
}
```

What i need from it is number, name of property (position, rotation etc.) and its value ((0,0,0) etc.)
I tried to develop part of regex pattern on https://regex101.com but without success. 
My pattern looks like this right now : `(\d{1}\.\d{3})\n\{\n(.*?\;\n)+\}`
It is supose to match every group with number + brackets and what's within it. It is working quite well on regex101 but in code it doesn't at all. 
Can any pro regex user tell me what's wrong with it and direct me into right path?
Cheers

Comment: You are using a wrong regex tester, regex101 does not support .NET. [Your pattern *captures* all the information you need.](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5cd%5c.%5cd%7b3%7d%29%5cr%3f%5cn%5c%7b%5cr%3f%5cn%28.*%3f%5c%3b%5cr%3f%5cn%29%2b%5c%7d&i=1.001%0d%0a%7b%0d%0aposition+%3d+%280%2c0%2c0%29%3b%0d%0arotation+%3d+%280.0%2c+0.0%2c+0.0%2c+1.0%29%3b%0d%0a%7d%0d%0a%0d%0a1.002%0d%0a%7b%0d%0arotation+%3d+%280.0%2c+0.0%2c+0.0%2c+1.0%29%3b%0d%0a%7d%0d%0a%0d%0a2.001%0d%0a%7b%0d%0aspawnOnStart+%3d+False%3b%0d%0a%7d) See *Table* tab, `$2` column.

Comment: You may also use a bit more precise `(?m)^(\d\.\d{3})\r?\n\{\r?\n(?:(.*);\r?\n)+}`, but you will have to collect the Group 2 capture collection using code

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [regex for c#](https://www.dotnetperls.com/regex) site for help.
Also you make this error:

```
    Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"content/([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)\.aspx$",
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    // Here we check the Match instance.
    if (match.Success)
    {
        // Finally, we get the Group value and display it.
        string key = match.Groups[1].Value;
        Console.WriteLine(key);
    }
```

Group value is the part you need to read. Every groups index counts one by one.

Choose python inside regex101 and only use information in this link.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that groups index starts at 1, not 0.

Comment: @Vifi yes, i forget. But trying for yourself also leads to learn the essential logic of the code.

Comment: @Vifi if it helped, you should upvote and sign it as a answer.

Comment: Thanks for care and trying but this post actually did not help me ;p That's why i didn't mark it. Guys in comment to my question told me that i am using bad site to build patterns for .NET and with some small changes my pattern did work. No less your link was also interesting and I learned a lot from them so thank you again!